# How to update a single column on a single row?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a simple update view for my Django REST application, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I've gotten a range of errors from 403 to 500.

Basically, I have a table 'Foo' and I want to set the 'active' field from 'True' to 'False'. Here's the view I have currently:

```
class DisableFoo(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        queryset = Foo.objects.filter(pk = self.request.data['id'])
        queryset.update(active = False)
```

However, this results in AssertionError:

```
Expected view DisableFoo to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk".
Fix your URL conf, or set the '.lookup_field' attribute on the view correctly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not send the `id` of the row you want to update with request.data but within the `url`.

So if you are hitting right now something like:

`/api/foo/`

try with

`/api/foo/<id>/`

of course this won't be enough. You should also consider a few more things.

You are hooking on `perform_update` method. But that's not likely to be correct. `perform_update` is called in order to update the whole object with `serializer.save()` and therefore it get called only when `serializer.is_valid()`.

This means that you will have to send a valid `Foo` object. But that's not what you want. You just need  to update a single field of the `Foo` object. So the right approach here is to use `partial_update`.  `partial_update` will be used when you make a [`PATCH`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#api-guide) request to `/api/foo/<id>/`

So if you send a `PATCH` request to `/api/foo/<id>/` with `active=0` inside request.data DRF will update the object automatically without any further code changes. Just using

```
class DisableFoo(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

But this will eventually expose all your model fields to update. So you can override the `partial_update` method like so:

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    instance.active = False
    instance.save(update_fields=['active'])
    return Response()
```

#### Another approach

DRF support creation of [extra extra-actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) via `@detail_route` and `@list_route` decorators.

You can use the `@detail_route` to create a custom disable action. Consider the following peace of code:

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def disable(self, request, pk=None):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.active = False
        instance.save(update_fields=['active'])
        return Response('done')
```

Making a `POST` request to `/api/foo/<id>/disable` will call the `disable` method we just wrote and disable the `foo` instance under `<id>`.

This way you can escape the requirement to use `PATCH` request method.

Comment: I changed it, but now I get HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST as a reply.

Comment: I update the answer with some explanations, but you should also learn how to debug such sort of errors by inspecting your error log.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the changes in a minute. In the meantime, do I have to set the `active=0` in the request if the request should always set the value to False? Wouldn't that be redundant? Also, my HTTP client doesn't support PATCH method.

Comment: If you don't override `partial_update` you will have to send it among the request. This basically tell the serializer which field to update with what values. So if you also send `active=0&some_other_field=some_other_value`, they will both get updated.

Comment: About the not supported `PATCH` method check my updated answer.